# .htaccess mod_rewrite country code prefix

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, internationalization

Lets say I have a site called example.com that has the following pages:

```
example.com
example.com/foo
example.com/bar
```

Now I want to create an Australian version of the site. The content for most pages will be the same on both sites but the URL structure will be:

```
example.com/au
example.com/au/foo
example.com/au/bar
```

All requests are already routed through index.php by the following in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

How can I alter this so both `example.com/foo` and `example.com/au/foo` are both routed though index.php. As far as index.php is concerned I want it to treat both pages in the same way.

The logic to determine which content to show will happen later and is out of the scope of this question.

Comment: But your current rule is already sending everything to `/index.php` so that should be good enough for `/au/` URLs also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**One Small Tweak**

I'm assuming that neither `foo` nor `bar` are actual directories.

- `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` checks that the request is not an existing file
- `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` checks that the request is not an existing directory

Both `example.com/foo` and `example.com/au/foo` meet these conditions, and will therefore follow the rule. Let's make one small tweak so that `index.php` does not get polluted by path fragments:

```
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L,DPI]
```

With that, you should be set. :)

Comment: Hey there, following up on this, did one of the answers solve it for you, or is the question still there?

Comment: Yes - this did answer my question. Like you said all paths are already getting routed though index.php so any further logic I need to do can be applied their.

Comment: Terrific. Thanks for letting me know, see you next time. :)